# Preventing EOF message on a Java RMI socket connection

Tags: java, ssh, connection, rmi, keep-alive

I have a Java application which uses RMI for client/server communication.
To secure this communication the traffic is tunneled through an ssh connection.

Everything works well, except that the connection keeps getting closed automatically after a few seconds.

I have set the keep alive property true of:

- SSHD connection
- SSH client connection
- ServerSocket server side
- ClientSocket client side

A common connection routine of connecting to the register (port 4000) and invoking a method on an object (port 4005) outputs the following log:

```
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession - Authentication succeeded
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession - Received SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN direct-tcpip
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelDirectTcpip - Receiving request for direct tcpip: hostToConnect=ThinkPad, portToConnect=4000, originatorIpAddress=127.0.0.1, originatorPort=64539
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession - Received SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN direct-tcpip
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelDirectTcpip - Receiving request for direct tcpip: hostToConnect=ThinkPad, portToConnect=4005, originatorIpAddress=127.0.0.1, originatorPort=64540
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelDirectTcpip - Received SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF on channel 1
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelDirectTcpip - Send SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_CLOSE on channel 1
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelDirectTcpip - Received SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_CLOSE on channel 1
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelDirectTcpip - Closing channel 1 immediately
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelDirectTcpip - Closing channel 1 immediately
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelDirectTcpip - Send SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF on channel 1
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.session.ServerSession - Closing session
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelDirectTcpip - Closing channel 0 immediately
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelDirectTcpip - Closing channel 0 immediately
INFO org.apache.sshd.server.channel.ChannelDirectTcpip - Send SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF on channel 0
```

The line ** Received SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EOF on channel 1 ** suggests that the method invoked on the object has generated an EOF message. This then causes the session to close...

Possible solutions I can think of:

- Intercept or prevent the EOF message (but where and how?)
- Try to configure the server side sessionfactory to ignore the EOF messages (feels wrong...)

Comment: As per [this site](http://www.networkdictionary.com/rfc/rfc4254.php?page=0%2C2) *EOF* shouldn't cause this connection to end.

Comment: But also as per that site SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_CLOSE certainly should close it, and it is being sent.

Comment: It looks like the server receives an EOF message and responds with a CLOSE message and after that the server sends an EOF itself. I wonder if the first received EOF is also send after closing the channel on the client side and how this can be prevented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RMI connections are pooled at the client and closed if not reused within 15 seconds. You can adjust this behaviour via system properties: see the Sun system properties page linked from the RMI home page.

Comment: Thank you EJP for the golden tip. The problem could be solved with a oneliner ( on the client side):

    System.setProperty("sun.rmi.transport.connectionTimeout", " 3600000");